# How to get bean values in jsp and store in a variable?

Tags: jsp

I can able to show this value in my page

```
<bean:write name="userProfileDomain" property="serviceRequestDomain.reqExpToDate" />
```

but i want to store this value in some variable in my jsp page and do some validation to it.

```
var i = <bean:write name="userProfileDomain" property="serviceRequestDomain.reqExpToDate"/>;
```

the above code doesn't work..any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2):

To assign to a Javascript variable , you can do :

```
var i = "${userProfileDomain.serviceRequestDomain.reqExpToDate}";
```